# How to set zoom factor in Mayavi

Tags: python, vtk, mayavi

I am trying to set the zoom factor in Mayavi2, for example:

```
from mayavi import mlab

mlab.test_plot3d()
mlab.show()
f = mlab.gcf()
cam = f.scene.camera
cam.zoom(0.1)
mlab.draw()
```

but nothing happens. The zoom is the same as before; have I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have just inverted 2 lines.
mlab.show() and mlab.draw() !

Try this:

```
from mayavi import mlab

currfig = mlab.test_plot3d()
mlab.draw()

cam = currfig.scene.camera
for ii in range(100):
  cam.zoom(0.99)
  mlab.draw()

mlab.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I missed the point with `show()` function. It seems like it have to be called at the end, since it does not return until the user quits the figure window..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mlab.view(distance=200)`

I don't know of a useful scale to tell you what exactly that distance number means though, I  use some experimenting to determine good values.