# Reproducing the camera angle of the following figure in Mayavi in Python

Tags: python, plot, mayavi

I have the following image that illustrates how a box is sheared:

[image: sheared box]

I want to plot my data as follows (note that the coordinates of the spheres are *not* sheared, i.e. the spheres reside in a perfectly cubic box)

[image: spheres data]

I have achieved the current positioning using `mlab` and the following code

```
# Achieve x-y view.
mlab.view(azimuth=0, elevation=0, distance=3.0)
# Rotate along x axis to expose part of the top of the box.
pts.actor.actor.rotate_x(30)
# Move camera down to compensate for rotation.
mlab.move(up=-0.37)
```

Is there a way to maneuver the camera such that the data look more like the illustration, by exposing some of the right side of the cube, while keeping the x-axis completely horizontal?

Edit: `mlab.view(azimuth=0, elevation=0, focalpoint=[4, 4, 0], distance=30.0)` produces the perspective I want. However, I am only able to see the box off to the side and into the distance. Zooming the camera causes the box to disappear from the image, since it zooms in to the point `x, y, z = [4, 4, 0]`. Is there a way I can "zoom back into" the relevant parts of the picture?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

According to http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_camera.html (function "view") you could use the arguments azimuth (xy rotation), elevation (z-angle) and distance (radius) as spherical coordinates.
For rotation of the xy-plane you should therefore change the azimuth to the desired angle (in degrees). so how about

```
mlab.view(azimuth=30, elevation=30, distance=3.0)
```

the rest of the following code can probably be complletly compensated with these 3 arguments

EDIT:
that was not the desired outcome, it was more like

```
mlab.view(azimuth=7.59, elevation=7.59, distance=30.0)
```

followed by a zoom in explained by stackoverflow.com/questions/25783180/how-to-set-zoom-factor-in-mayavi
see also the comments of this answer

Comment: No, this doesn't produce something that has the x-y plane in front-view. After experimenting with the azimuthal and elevation angle, I don't think there is a way to do achieve a view of the top and right side of the box, while keeping the x-axis horizontal, while also keeping the box in the origin.

Comment: how about moving the camera to the side? the mayavi.mlab.move method has also arguments for forward and right (I guess you need "right"), that should rotate the plot, but be aware, that the focal point is also shifted.
try adding to your code:
mlab.move(right=0.3)
mayavi.mlab.yaw(5)

I'm unsure about the sign, see also pitch and roll, if the direction is wrong

Comment: `move(right=4, up=4)` without the yaw produces the viewpoint I want. I think it is equivalent to the following: `mlab.view(azimuth=0, elevation=0, focalpoint=[4, 4, 0], distance=30.0)`. However, I am only able to see the box off to the side and into the distance. Is there a way I can "zoom back into" the relevant parts of the picture? See updated OP.

Comment: First you must turn the camera to point at the center using pitch, yaw and roll (I think you need only the first two) and then you can zomm. Zooming was already asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25783180/how-to-set-zoom-factor-in-mayavi

for the camera turn I assume that you need (modulo sign) to pitch AND yaw by an angle of arcsin(4/30)=7.66°. so as code: mlab.yaw(7.66) mlab.pitch(7.66)

If It's not working with it, try changing the signs and maybe use roll instead one of the other two functions. If it works: think about outlining the edges of the box for a clearer view

Comment: It's not the arcsin, use arctan instead... arctan(4/30)=7.59° (small change here)